# Finding a substring in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say that I have these strings:

```
My dog is young  

I have a _dog_ 

Dogs are fine
```

I want to get any string that has `dog` in it *only*. This means I want only the first row to return. The two others, contains marks like `_` which I don't want to get, or it has an extra `s` at the end.

I've tried doing something like:

```
$('#side-categories a').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href.indexOf(table) >= 0) {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
        $(this).parents("ul").show().prev('.do').text('-');
    }
});
```

But it also returns the `_dog_` and the `Dogs`

Suggestions?

Comment: You may want to use a regular expression.

Comment: I don't see a reason to down vote my post. I really have no knowledge or experience with regex. If you could help me, it would be great.

Comment: Just to be clear: `href.indexOf(table) >= 0` is your attempt to search for "dog"? Is `"dog"` the value of `table`?

Comment: The code you have has nothing to do with filtering the word 'dog' from the strings you pasted...

Comment: @C.S. It was a demonstration only

Comment: @kfirba: I didn't downvote your post, so why do you assume I did? Here, I'll upvote it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an ideal case for regular expressions!

In this case, you want to do this:

```
$('#side-categories a').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if(href.match(/\sdog\s/)){
        $(this).css("color", "red");
        $(this).parents("ul").show().prev('.do').text('-');
    }
});
```

Regular expressions are a good thing to learn.  In this case, it's pretty basic.  `/\sdog\s/` is saying "a regular expression containing some whitespace, the lowercase string dog and some more whitespace."  That includes your first line, while eliminating your second (due to the whitespace) and the third (do to the exact string `dog` followed by whitespace).

If you're using a variable (such as `table`?) to hold the string you're looking for, you need to construct the regular expression.  The important lines then become:

```
var regex = new RegExp("\s" + table + "\s");
if(href.match(regex)){
```

Based on your comments, it looks like you want to see if the string starts with `dog`.  If that's the case, you can use regex - you just want `new RegExp("^" + table)`.  But in **that** case, you actually could do better with a regular string function, such as `if (href.indexOf(table) == 0)`.

In the case of looking for `table=dog*`, that's a fairly easy RegExp as well:  `new RegExp("table=" + table)`.  This looks for `table=dog` to be anywhere in the string.  Without regexp, you'd do similar to above, `if (href.indexOf("table=" + table) != -1)`.

Comment: While passing a string to `.match` is OK, passing an actual regular expression would be cleaner.

Comment: What if I want to pass a parameter instead of `dog`?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Thanks! But for some reason, it doesn't work for me. I will explain a lil bit more. I'm looking for a substring in a string that looks something like: `/table.php?table=xxxname=yyy` then I'm trying to see if xxx has the regex that I'm looking for. I have the xxx value in a hidden element on the page, so it's not the problem. but I think your code is refering to whitespaces delimiter, but there are actuallu none. there may be this sign: `_` and may be nothing.

Comment: @kfirba: See, and that's why it's good to provide a real example of your problem, not just "some demonstration". Now we wasted a lot of time on solutions which don't help. It looks like you want to check whether the query string of a URL contains a parameter with a certain value, is that correct? Does your search term have to match a value exactly or only partially? There are already exiting solutions for extracting the parameters and values of a query string.

Comment: @kfirba This should really be a comment and update to the question instead of my answer.  You're getting closer to defining exactly what you want.  Does xxx have to be exactly the term you're looking for?  I know `_dog_` and `dogs` aren't ok, what about `foodog` and `dogfoo` and `-dog`?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you want it to start with `dog`?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Starting with the expression may actually solve the problem

Comment: @kfirba Updated, but I do agree with @FelixKling's comment - we took a long way around to solve your problem.  That simple line of `/table.php?table=xxxname=yyy` made your issue much more clear.

Comment: So, you always want to test whether the value of a specific parameter in the query string matches your input? Maybe you should first extract the value form the URL then: http://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/218196.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I'm sorry that I'm annoying you, but the string that I'm getting from the `href` var, doesn't start with what I want. What I want to 'scan' is the value of `table` within the link: `/table.php?table=SCAN_THIS&name=yyy`

Comment: @kfirba Ok, here's my final answer.  (It's way past my bedtime!)  If you need any further help, I'll be on in a few hours, or someone else can jump in from here.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Thanks scot! works like magic! Just for you to know, for some reason, the Regex method **doesn't** work. The second one without the Regex, works perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(href.match(/ dog /g)){
    $(this).css("color", "red");
    $(this).parents("ul").show().prev('.do').text('-');
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsK4L/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by using regex, but you would have to explicitly define that the word that you're using in the matching pattern has a space before it and after it, which is kind of wierd.

The condition that you're looking for is the one which splits the setence to words, because otherwise `_dog_` sentence would be returned too. So:

```
function checkForWord(word, sentence)
{
    wordArray = sentence.split(" ");
    for(i=0; i<wordArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(wordArray[i] == word)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
alert(checkForWord("dog", "My dog is young"));
```